Tikkun for my son
I'm looking to offer my son, who's started leyning a lot more, a nice Tikkun.
I've heard a lot about the

Simanim
Chorev
Kestenbaum

He's probably going to go to rabbinical school at one point so I want this to be a nice, beautiful, long lasting gift for him to use when he'll be a rabbi.
Any advice ?
We're Ashkenazi, but he's also learning a Sephardi trope since he likes music and he's connected to a lot of Sephardic schuls. So what would be the difference inside between an Ashkenazic version of the Tikkun and a Sephardic one ?
I saw this post, however it's quite old and does not really compare the 3 editions, especially in their latest format. Unless nothing has changed in the past 5-7 years, which is perfectly possible.
Thanks a lot for your help, I'm hoping to find that for him for Hannukah.

Welcome to MiYodeya Imanuel and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

related (dup?): Looking for a good tikkun kor'im

Thanks for your answer.
I saw this post, however it's quite old and does not really compare the 3 editions, especially in their latest format.
Unless nothing has changed in the past 5-7 years, which is perfectly possible.

This question is similar to: Looking for a good tikkun kor'im. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Aren't the notations the same regardless of the nusach?

Notation will probably be the same but cutting, page setting,... will probably be different, as would an Ashkenazi Sefer Torah differ in page layout from a Sphardi, and the information about Alyot, etc might also be different. Hence my question to people who might have a more specific answer.
But apparently my questions are bothering some people despite the fact that I clearly explained why the other post was indeed informative but did not answer my questions completely and with up to date info.

"up to date info" is not a reason to re-ask the same thing. You can start a bounty on the old question if "current answers are outdated". If the question is just "what would be the difference inside between an Ashkenazic version of the Tikkun and a Sephardic one?" then that could be better emphasized, such as by removing some of the surrounding text. (Though that too might be a duplication of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/143216/759)
